# What's difference of this code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char s[] = "dog";
    char t[] = "house";
    char temp[]="";

    strncpy(temp, s, 2);

    return 0;

}
```

Then temp is address of first character of "do"; 
I adjust this code by char temp[] to char *temp
But This code is error, why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char s[] = "dog";
    char t[] = "house";
    char *temp;

    strncpy(temp, s, 2);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to C, where you need to do your own memory allocation.  You can't copy strings into an empty array `char temp[]`, or into an uninitialized pointer `char *temp`.  You have to decide how much space you want, and explicitly allocate that much: either `char temp[100]`, or `char *temp = malloc(100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both codes are wrong.

The first only allocates space for 1 character in `temp` but copies 2.

The second takes the address of a string literal and writes into the string literal through that address. String literals are read-only, so this could crash.

All of this are errors that your compiler must not necessarily diagnose (the technical term is "the behavior is undefined").